# How can I get changed methods in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, build-process, regression-testing

I've spent the last few weeks trying to figure out a way to implement (or find someone who has implemented) regressive testing  for our build process, but so far I haven't found anything that works. We use TFS2008 and VS2010, and upgrading to TFS2010 is not an option for us. I've tried to use NDepend to give us the list of changed methods and type dependencies, but running it through our build script has proven supremely unreliable (if I run the same build twice without changing anything I would not be surprised to have one perfect NDepend report, and one exception saying NDepend can't run for one reason or another).

Unfortunately, I'm pretty much stuck with the tools I have (TFS2008, VS2010, MSBuild, and MSTest). I could probably get another tool, but changing the tools I already have (such as moving from MSTest to NUnit, or TFS2008 to TFS2010) will not be possible.

Has anyone does this already? Or can someone point me in the right direction to find which methods and types changed between two builds programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have unit tests and a coverage report.  Then you could diff the coverage report before and after.  Any changes to the coverage would be shown in that.  You could then regression test off that (which I assume is manual)